# An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'array'

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am using pandas_udf() to run python functions on PySpark dataframes.
I am getting stuck on an error

PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'array''.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame( 
    [(25, 20, .25), 
    (20, 20, .22), 
    (35, 20, .67)], 
    ["control_mean", "control_sd", "pooled_se"]
)

df.show()


def foo(control_mean: pd.Series, control_sd: pd.Series, pooled_se: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    
    mu_null = 0

    ##Calculate Likelihood of Null
    pdf = stats.norm.pdf(control_mean, mu_null, pooled_se)
 
    return(pdf)


foo_pudf = F.pandas_udf(foo, returnType=T.FloatType())

df.withColumn(
    "pdf", 
    foo_pudf(
        F.col("control_mean"), 
        F.col("control_sd"), 
        F.col("pooled_se")
    )
).show()
```

The output from `stats.norm.pdf` seems to trigger the error. This output is of type `numpy.float64`. But I can use `numpy.float64` output from `np.sqrt()` within other pandas_udf without issue. So I am not sure what is causing the error here.

Comment: The output of `pdf` is not a `numpy.float64`.  You are giving it a series, so it's going to produce an array of float64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a pandas Series from pandas_udf:

```py
@F.pandas_udf(T.FloatType())
def foo(control_mean: pd.Series, control_sd: pd.Series, pooled_se: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    mu_null = 0
    ##Calculate Likelihood of Null
    pdf = stats.norm.pdf(control_mean, mu_null, pooled_se)
    return pd.Series(pdf)


df.withColumn(
    "pdf", 
    foo(
        F.col("control_mean"), 
        F.col("control_sd"), 
        F.col("pooled_se")
    )
).show()

+------------+----------+---------+---+
|control_mean|control_sd|pooled_se|pdf|
+------------+----------+---------+---+
|          25|        20|     0.25|0.0|
|          20|        20|     0.22|0.0|
|          35|        20|     0.67|0.0|
+------------+----------+---------+---+
```

**A tip to debug pandas_udf**

Change the return type of pandas_udf to StringType and return series with length equal to number of rows. For each element of the returned series, you can use some debug entry in text form or leave unused as empty string.

For example: In the following output, we print

- type of `pdf`
- shape of `pdf`
- string representation of `pdf`

```py
@F.pandas_udf(T.StringType())
def foo(control_mean: pd.Series, control_sd: pd.Series, pooled_se: pd.Series) -> pd.Series:
    mu_null = 0
    ##Calculate Likelihood of Null
    pdf = stats.norm.pdf(control_mean, mu_null, pooled_se)
    return pd.Series([str(type(pdf)), str(pdf.shape), str(pdf)])


df.withColumn(
    "pdf", 
    foo(
        F.col("control_mean"), 
        F.col("control_sd"), 
        F.col("pooled_se")
    )
).show(truncate=False)

+------------+----------+---------+-----------------------+
|control_mean|control_sd|pooled_se|pdf                    |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------------+
|25          |20        |0.25     |<class 'numpy.ndarray'>|
|20          |20        |0.22     |(3,)                   |
|35          |20        |0.67     |[0. 0. 0.]             |
+------------+----------+---------+-----------------------+
```